# App crashes after keyboard shows only in TestFlight release and IOS 14

Tags: swift, crash, keyboard, ios14

I am not having this problem when I debbuging it. However when we are testing the app with downloading it from TestFlight this problem occurs. Problem is; in our Login page after fill username and password textfields then press Login button app is crashes every time only in IOS 14.

Note: When keyboard is active app screen goes top to make visible password textfield. After that when user press Login button, firstly to close keyboard resignFirstResponde code works and then  next codes works 0.2 second after (Dispatch Async Main After) to prevent bad looking.

```
 self.resignTextField(item: self.view)
 self.loginButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) { [weak self] in
    self?.loginButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self?.viewModel.login(username: username, password: password)
 }
```

Does anyone facing this problem? This problem occurs in our all ios 14 installed test devices..

```
    "share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 14.0 (18A373)"
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, <RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-update watchdog transgression: application<com.myapp>:3256 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Background | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-update | WatchdogVisibility: Background | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 18.650 (user 18.650, system 0.000), 31% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 9.934, 17% CPU" | ) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001adebe148 0x1ade96000 + 164168
1   UIKitCore                       0x000000019d3c7b8c 0x19c397000 + 16976780
2   QuartzCore                      0x000000019d8b94c0 0x19d769000 + 1377472
3   QuartzCore                      0x000000019d8c242c 0x19d769000 + 1414188
4   QuartzCore                      0x000000019d8c1f3c 0x19d769000 + 1412924
5   QuartzCore                      0x000000019d8c6d44 0x19d769000 + 1432900
6   QuartzCore                      0x000000019d8c77b0 0x19d769000 + 1435568
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000019d3a677c 0x19c397000 + 16840572
8   UIKitCore                       0x000000019d185034 0x19c397000 + 14606388
9   UIKitCore                       0x000000019d1ba018 0x19c397000 + 14823448
10  UIKitCore                       0x000000019d1b5b94 0x19c397000 + 14805908
11  UIKitCore                       0x000000019d3bd954 0x19c397000 + 16935252
12  QuartzCore                      0x000000019d8bd9e8 0x19d769000 + 1395176
13  QuartzCore                      0x000000019d8c3eb4 0x19d769000 + 1420980
14  UIKitCore                       0x000000019d3aa2b8 0x19c397000 + 16855736
15  UIKitCore                       0x000000019d1c811c 0x19c397000 + 14881052
16  MyApp                       0x00000001000d40c4 0x1000cc000 + 32964
17  UIKitCore                       0x000000019d3bd954 0x19c397000 + 16935252
18  QuartzCore                      0x000000019d8bd9e8 0x19d769000 + 1395176
19  QuartzCore                      0x000000019d8c3eb4 0x19d769000 + 1420980
20  QuartzCore                      0x000000019d8cf1d0 0x19d769000 + 1466832
21  QuartzCore                      0x000000019d81b500 0x19d769000 + 730368
22  QuartzCore                      0x000000019d845698 0x19d769000 + 902808
23  QuartzCore                      0x000000019d846948 0x19d769000 + 907592
24  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019a5f7ecc 0x19a55f000 + 626380
25  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019a5f25b0 0x19a55f000 + 603568
26  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019a5f2af8 0x19a55f000 + 604920
27  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019a5f2200 0x19a55f000 + 602624
28  GraphicsServices                0x00000001b06ed598 0x1b06ea000 + 13720
29  UIKitCore                       0x000000019ceb8004 0x19c397000 + 11669508
30  UIKitCore                       0x000000019cebd5d8 0x19c397000 + 11691480
31  PrivateSDK                      0x0000000104fa208c 0x101638000 + 60203148
32  MyApp                       0x00000001000ddc78 0x1000cc000 + 72824
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019a2d1598 0x19a2d0000 + 5528
```

Comment: What does the crash log say?  (Error message?  Stack trace?)

Comment: Hi @PhillipMills I shared edited the question

Comment: @GokhanAlp did you solve this? we seem to have the same exact problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. Older Material.io TextField in Secure Text mode causes memory problem only in iOS 14. So I updated it problem fixed.